# arules subset not working in the new version (1.5-2) of arules package

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I recently updated by Arules package to version 1.5-2, ever since I am not able to subset item list from Rule set, I get the following error when I try to subset
"Error in structure(seq(length(labels)), names = labels)[i] : 
  invalid subscript type 'S4'" here is an example

```
library(arules)
data("Groceries")

#generate Rules without second record to create an itemset
rules <- apriori(Groceries[-2],parameter = list(supp = 0.05, conf = 0.2,target = "rules"))

#Create an itemlist with second record
enter code here`basket <- Groceries[2]
rulesMatchLHS <- is.subset(rules@lhs,basket)
suitableRules <- rulesMatchLHS & !(is.subset(rules@rhs,basket))
#output
inspect(rules[suitableRules])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subset vector looks like a sparse matrix, but a dense logical vector is needed:

```
suitableRules

7 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"
                   {tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee}
{}                                              |
{yogurt}                                        |
{whole milk}                                    .
{rolls/buns}                                    .
{whole milk}                                    .
{other vegetables}                              .
{whole milk}                                    .

as.logical(suitableRules)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

inspect(rules[as.logical(suitableRules)])
    lhs         rhs          support   confidence lift     count
[1] {}       => {whole milk} 0.2555420 0.2555420  1.000000 2513 
[2] {yogurt} => {whole milk} 0.0560301 0.4018964  1.572722  551
```

Comment: thank you.. this work, but when I try to remove redundant rules I  still face a challenge get a error - invalid subscript type 'S4' code I use is this : `rules[suitableRules][!is.redundant(rules[suitableRules])]`

Comment: `srules <- rules[as.logical(suitableRules)]; srules[!is.redundant(srules)]` works for me.